# Wrap WordPress Login Form in custom Div

Tags: customization, filters, css, login

I'm customizing the WordPress login form with the help of the [WordPress Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form). I'm using the described filters to alter the appearance of the form, mainly by injecting new CSS styles.

I'd now like to vertically centre the login form on the page if the viewport is larger than the form. This can be easily done with flexbox by wrapping the `div#login` with a `div.wrapper` and using the following CSS styles:

```
body.login {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    .wrapper {
        max-height: 100vh;
        max-width: 100vh;
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is, that I have to wrap the current `div#login` with the `.wrapper` div. How could I do this? I cannot find any filter or other method allowing this.

Comment: Sorry, but why do you have to wrap the login into another div? What's the issue of applying the styles to the `body` itself and remove the padding from `#login`? This will center the box already. If you want to center for specific sizes you can use media queries.

Comment: @FabianMarz Yeah, that would already centre the `div#login` but there is an issue if the viewport *height* is smaller than the height of the `div#login`. By using the wrapper, that div would be centred on the page and as I limit it to the viewport size, it's content will be normally scrollable if it's larger, otherwise, it will stay centred. See what I mean?